# Inner join returning large numbers of duplicates

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am using the following query to join two tables together:

```
SELECT SDA.smachIPAddress,
DPP.ScanName,
DPP.pspplMSSeverity,
DPP.PatchMissing,
DPP.ScanDate
FROM patchtest_withsev DPP
INNER JOIN patchtest_withip SDA
ON DPP.ScanName =SDA.ScanName
```

and receiving 2351 rows of data

When I query the patchtest_withsev table for all records it only returns 99 and the patchtest_withip table only returns 99.

Can anyone see why this query is producing such a large mismatch?

Comment: can you put part of your tables in SQL fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) to have a better idea of your issue?

Comment: Why do you think there's a mismatch?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that both table have several rows with same values of `ScanName`.

For example:

```
table1:
f1 | f2
 1 | a
 1 | b
 2 | c
 2 | c

table2:
f1 | f2
 1 | a
 1 | b
 2 | c
```

table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.f1 = table2.f1 gives:

```
table1.f1 | table1.f2 | table2.f1 | table2.f2
        1 |         a |         1 |         a
        1 |         a |         1 |         b
        1 |         b |         1 |         a
        1 |         b |         1 |         b
        2 |         c |         2 |         c
        2 |         c |         2 |         c
```

To avoid completely duplicate rows in result try using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed example so that `DISTINCT` will make results different.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have duplicate values for ScanName in either table? If so, then SQL will return one row for every match, which inflates the number of rows very quickly. (e.g., if there are 3 rows with a given value in the first table and 6 rows with that value in the second, SQL will return 18 rows).

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple records in `patchtest_withip` that match the criteria you are joining on from `patchtest_withsev` you could get results like that.  Based on the results you are getting I would say there are 23-24 records in `patchtest_withip` that have the same `ScanName` as every record in `patchtest_withsev`

Answer (score 0):

If there are 99 entries in each table, assuming there were no unique values for scanName, you could potentially have 99x99=9801 entries in your results.

If you are getting true duplicates, try SELECT DISTINCT.